# Как преобразовывать в строки в языке C?

Tags: c, строки

Есть число: 123. Я хочу его сделать строчным, тип данных - String. "123".

Можно ли как то это сделать?

Comment: Откуда и по какой логике должна взяться цифра 3?

Comment: это 123, я не дописал

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c

Comment: По первому же запросу в гугле вываливаетя масса иформации. Вопрос задан лишь для того чтобы задать вопрос?!

Comment: Кстати, типа данных String в языке C не существует

Answer (score 3):

Воспользоваться стандартной функцией

```
to_string(123)
```

См. [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Если вы о C-строках - `char[]` - то тогда `sprintf`

Answer (score 0):

Типа string в Си нет. Самый оптимальный способ создать подобие строки - это создать массив символов, например:

`char str[] = "Hello";`

Это эквивалент такой записи:

`char str[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};`

Вывести можно так
`printf("%s\n", str);`

Или

```
for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    printf("%c", str[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Вопрос был не о выводе (печати)  `char[]`, а о **его заполнении** цифрами числа (в виде символов)